# Numba Vectorize FakeOverload

Tags: python, ubuntu, numba

This program gives an error when it gets to the "@vectorize(['float32(float32)'], target='cuda')" function with the error:

```
File "/home/idf/anaconda3/envs/gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cuda/vectorizers.py", line 206, in _compile_core
    return cudevfn, cudevfn.overloads[sig.args].signature.return_type
AttributeError: 'FakeOverload' object has no attribute 'signature'
```

Notice that I am not even calling the `function`. It seems to be an error at the `interpreter` stage:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numba import vectorize,guvectorize,cuda

import timeit

def numpy_sqrt_x(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)

def math_sqrt_x(x):
    return [math.sqrt(xx) for xx in x]

@vectorize
def cpu_sqrt(x):
  return math.sqrt(x)

@vectorize(['float32(float32)'], target='cuda')
def gpu_sqrt(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.arange(10)
    print(x**2)

    #print(np.exp(x))
    #x = np.arange(int(1e2))
    #print(timeit.timeit("numpy_sqrt_x(x)", globals=globals()))
    #print(timeit.timeit("math_sqrt_x(x)", globals=globals()))

    #print(gpu_sqrt(x))
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have any trouble with the code you have posted.

Comment: The same for me (on Windows with Numba 0.55.2). What about using `@vectorize('float32(float32)', target='cuda')`? Note that `x` variable in the main section is of type `nb.int_` and not a `np.float32`.